# Stored procedure vs. Entity Framework (LINQ queries)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, stored-procedures

I would like to ask what is better to use for database transactions?

I am wondering what is the best practice or if there is a technical explanation of what and when to use stored procedure or just pure LINQ entity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are quite a few similar questions hanging around here on SO.

Comment: alright.. @ChrisCruz I keep reading and reading however I don't get the exact idea of when it is better to use stored proc or what is better to use for the project.

Comment: @MaxMokrousov Thanks for the link...

Comment: @MaxMokrousov very well said.. the idea is use EF as much as possible, use stored proc if needed(ex. performance issue etc.). Thanks!

Comment: @Drew Aguirre welcome